# How do I make MySQL use IP instead of hostnames?

Tags: mysql

I created a user, `foo@IP`, and granted it some permissions. When I try to connect to that MySQL server from the machine with ip `IP` I get the error: `Message: Access denied for user 'foo'@'HOSTNAME' (using password: YES)`, where `HOSTNAME` matches `IP` but I want to use `IP` because that's what all the other servers are using (and I don't want to deal with DNS resolution).

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

To add a bit more details, this is when setting up a replica, so both ends of the connection is a MySQL replica. All users and replicas are using IPs when connecting and when defining the users. I'm not sure why this, the latest replica I'm setting up, behaves differently.